# Is code execution slower when called remotely? (.net remoting)

Tags: .net, performance, remoting

I have a sub in my VB.NET (framework 2) program. This sub does not return any value, it just perform various checks on a local DB.

The program calls the sub just after starts, and it takes about 6 seconds to complete.

The program also acts as a net remoting server. Clients can connect to it and call the sub.

When a remote client calls the sub it takes about 28 seconds to complete.

Why is that? In both cases the sub is executed locally in the server, but when called remotely it takes a lot more time, even if the task is exactly the same.

Is somehow the code executed in a much slower thread when called using .net remoting?

Do you know why this happens?

Do you know how to solve it?

Thank you for any help!

EDIT:

I am very sorry for the lack of information. I thought it would be enough. OK here it goes…

This is a VB sub, it does not return any value.

Network is fast, the problem is not to reach the remote computer, the problem is that the code seems to take a lot more to complete if called remotely.

If you really want to know, the main part of the sub is a loop that copies values from a DAO (yes DAO) recordset to a collection:

```
Sub MySub
'This sub can be called both remotemy and locally.

Dim IDsAtTable As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

‘Open database and fast stuff. 
‘{…}

‘POINT A
RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM " & Table & " WHERE IDSucursalFuente=" & IDThisSucursal & " ORDER BY ID")
Fld = RS.Fields("ID")
Do While Not RS.EOF
    ID = Fld.Value
    If Not IDsAtTable.ContainsKey(ID) Then IDsAtTable.Add(ID, ID)
    RS.MoveNext()
Loop
RS.Close()
RS = Nothing
‘POINT B

'Check elements stored at IDsAtTable, this is fast.

‘Close database and fast stuff.
‘{…}    
End Sub
```

In both cases (when called remotely and when called locally on the server) the code works with the same DB (hosted on the server), in the same state (I mean closed at the beginning) with the exact same records.

If you measure time from POINT A to POINT B it takes a lot more time if the sub was called remotely, but as you can see, there is no network involved. To me it should take the same amount of time but that’s not the case.

I only call the sub 2 times. One locally by the server process itself, and one by the remote client.

Server's processor load is the same. There is just one client calling the sub at a given time.

I don’t know if .NET framework does other stuff behind the scenes when executes code that was called remotely, or if the thread created for a remote call is much slower.

Comment: You've given zero details about what the function does, what it returns, how often it's called, etc. So I'm going to venture a guess and say that the remote sub must be returning a lot of data over a slow connection. Either that or it's being called many times over a high latency connection.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've given absolutely no information that would allow anyone to help you with this situation. Please edit your question to provide sufficient details, or it will most likely be closed as "not a real question". Remember we don't know anything about your problem except what you tell us here in your question - we can't see your monitor from here. If you want help, you need to give us the information we can use to do so. Thanks. :)

Comment: A couple of things. The first time the sub is called remotely, the client and server have to negotiate the connection. Do all remote calls take 28 seconds? Or just the first one? Second, if you're passing data to the sub, be sure that you're passing the actual object and not a proxy for the object. If you're passing a proxy and the server has to access properties on that object, it will be making remote calls back to the client to get those properties.

Comment: Chris and Ken, thank you. Hope my edit help you to understand better. Jim, thank you. It always take about 28 seconds. The problem is not reaching anything on the network, the problem seems to be the actual speed to complete the loop.

Comment: I found something interesting: at http://tinypic.com/r/slpn2a/7 I posted the graph of the CPU usage for the code execution, as reported by sysinternals process explorer. As you can see, it takes a lot more time to do the same task when called remotely even if in both cases the task is executed fully on the server. The colors of the graph may indicate something. I found that "The red color showcases the kernel mode and the green signifies the transition of Kernel and User mode", what does than mean? Is that related somehow to the problem?

Comment: What type of remoting channel are you using? Serializing/deserializing a large amount of data to XML (if you are using a SOAP channel) could take a lot of time. If you're using SOAP, try using a TCP channel (binary) instead and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Another thing that can affect remoting performance on the initial connection is if the client can reach the server via IPv6 but the server isn't listening on it (and it won't be unless you explicitly configured a remoting channel to listen on IPv6). The client will try to connect with IPv6, time out after several seconds, and only then try IPv4. This only affects the first call though, it doesn't impact anything once the connection is established.

Comment: Hello. As I said, the problem is not network related, connection is very fast, remote sub starts executing almost instantly and it does not return any value. It is the code inside the sub that takes a lot of time to execute if is called remotely.

Comment: Thank all of you for viewing this question. However, I have narrowed down this problem: It seems this is not related at all with remoting, but with using DAO in a secondary thread. I have created another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541276/accessing-data-in-a-secondary-thread-is-much-slower perhaps you may want to take a look, it is much more clear. Finally, I don't seem to find a way to delete this question, can someone help me with that please?